# Locking user account in a specific way

Tags: linux, accounts, lock

I've been tasked with performing a lockdown on a user account (making it impossible to properly login-in to) in a very specific way. Im prohibited from:

a) Altering his password (so passwd -l is out as I take it)

b) Altering its expiration date ( so no chage -E)

c) Changing its shell (no chsh)

I honostly have no idea how to handle this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to set the directory permissions of the user's home directory to exclude the executable bit (`0xx`, `2xx`, `4xx`, `6xx` would all work.) If the user tries to log in, they'll get an error like this:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/erik: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that:
- the user is logging in via ssh
- you need to prohibit the user from logging in

The DenyUsers directive in sshd_config should be the path forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the 'logout' command to the 1st line of .bashrc

```
sed -i '1i logout' /home/jdoe/.bashrc
```

To rollback (be sure 'logout' is at 1st line):

```
sed -i '1d' /home/jdoe/.bashrc
```